# Nuxt/Vue Printing in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, safari, nuxt.js

Calling `window.print()` in a function fails to bring up the Safari native print window. This does however work in Chrome.

I've tried:

- Attempting to follow [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print) causes nothing to happen when the button is tapped. Is there a special way I need to attach this to a button in Nuxt/Vue?
- Using `document.execCommand('print', false, null)` occasionally works but 90% of the time will show a 100+ page document with no content in the print dialog.

macOS 12.3,
Safari 15.4,
Nuxt 2.15.7

Comment: The second one is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand Do you have an error with `window.print()` in the console?

Comment: Also, try this with a simple HTML file, then a simple Vue.js app then Nuxt, would be a nice way to debug and understand what is not working here. Since most people doesn't really have any debugging experience regarding `print`.

Comment: No error message in console. When I try it on a simple HTML site it works fine the first time, but then the second time you try the print window will also have a large amount of empty pages. Seems to work again the next time you refresh the page :/. Will try actually triggering the print window in Vue/Nuxt.

Comment: In Vue ```<button onclick="window.print()">Print!</button>``` works to open the print window (ignoring the issue mentioned in the comment above).

Comment: This doesn't work in Nuxt, I assume the special `@click` prop is required instead of the `onclick`. However then the error I get is `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_vm.window.print')`.

Comment: If it's not working in HTML, you should maybe focus on this one in prio, no need to go higher in abstraction (Vue + Nuxt). Does it work 100% on Safari? Or does it work perfectly in Vue for some reason? Btw, `onclick` is an HTML thing, not to be used. It's also `onClick` in React. But in Vue, you only use `@click`. Of course having some more code or even a [repro] may help a bit more. If there is nothing special to repro, I guess that focus on solving the thing to have it working in this order is still the best thing to do: HTML -> Vue -> Nuxt.

Comment: In Nuxt3 it works like this: `@click="print"` and then in the script setup: `const print = () => window.print();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be two problems going on here:

1. Calling `window.print()` in Nuxt does not bring up the Safari print window.
2. Safari displays the correct print window only the first time, then just a bunch of blank pages. This does not seem to be limited to Nuxt, though ([example](https://github.com/gregnb/react-to-print/issues/397)).

As for the first problem, I found this [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195769) that an active `EventSource` prevents Safari from displaying the print window. So i thought hmmm, maybe the Nuxt dev server is somehow using this to communicate with the client. So I tried running my app in production mode (`nuxt build && nuxt start`) and voilà, this made my Safari print window appear as expected.

Comment: Right, I hope OP tried to build it.

Comment: I was indeed using Nuxt dev mode, evidently this is causing issues as you say. Building and starting the application works as you mention. Therefore I think the main issue here is actually Safari specific rather than an Nuxt issue. I wonder if there is a bug report for raised for this with the Safari team.